# C - how to find a remainder of two numbers?

Tags: c

how can I  do the sum of the remainder of two numbers as it is in sum2
and whole number 7+4 ?

7.605, 4.331
  sum1 = 11
  sum2 = 0.936

Comment: What part are you confused about?

Comment: Add. truncate, subtract.

Comment: Start with `int main (){ return 0;}`

Comment: when a user enter a number i want the program will give me as above

Answer (score 1):

C has a nice function `modf()` in `<math.h>` for this.

> The `modf` functions break the argument value into integral and fractional parts, each of which has the same type and sign as the argument. ...  C11dr §7.12.6.12 2

```
double x = 7.605;
double y = 4.331;
double sum_ipart;
double sum_fpart = modf(x+y, &sum_ipart);
printf("%.3f + %.3f = %.0f and fraction %.3f\n", x, y, sum_ipart, sum_fpart);
```

Output

```
7.605 + 4.331 = 11 and fraction 0.936
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#include <math.h>
float sum = 7.605f + 4.331f;
int sum1 = floor(sum);
float sum2 = sum - sum1;
```

Comment: That won't work in case of 7.605 and 4.4.
You should use `floor` for both input numbers to `sum1` and employ same method to retrieve `sum2`

Comment: my meaning was that a user enter a number and I want it to display the answer, I just don't know how to  tell it to calculate the remainder alone as i said for example: 2.5 +2.4

Comment: Better to use `floorf()` with `float` arguments and `floor()` with `double`. (Since C99).  Why assign the result of `floor()` to an `int`?  Assigning to a `float` would prevent overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Separate out integer and fractional parts of both numbers and then add integer parts to get sum1, and add fractional parts to get sum2.

```
float n1, n2;
int n1_int, n2_int;
float n1_frac, n2_frac;
n1_int = floor(n1);
n2_int = floor(n2);
n1_frac = n1 - n1_int;
n2_frac = n2 - n2_int;
sum1 = n1_int + n2_int;
sum2 = n1_frac + n2_frac;
```

Comment: This fails 1) when the sum of the fractional parts exceed 1.0 2) When the `float` value > `INT_MAX` - code could have used `float n1_int, n2_int;` to take care of that.  It also has curious results when `n1, n2` are negative.